# Finding similar users

Tags: classification, feature-selection, similarities

I am working on a problem in the online advertising space. I am trying to identify consumers similar to the set of consumers who have bought a product in the past (have 'converted'). If I can identify 'similar' users, I can deliver them targeted messaging with the goal of turning them into paying customers.

I have approached this as a predictive modeling problem. I have been using KNN and logistic regression to determine major factors that influence the target variable ('being a converter').

I feel that I am approaching this wrong, as in my set of 'non-converters' I have a set of people who are quite similar in every way to 'converters'. So if I built a perfect model it would not be helpful in detecting 'non-converters' who should be 'converters'.

My ultimate goal is to detect the non-converters who behave similarly to converters. Should my goal with the model be to predict converters with high accuracy, and argue that users classified as converters who were actually non-converters fall into the set of consumers I should be targeting?

Can someone help push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

How else would you distinguish between them? In any supervised learning you have inputs and target, which should be defined for training set. You know who has converted and who not, you can't just guess - it is a binary thing. How do you know that those who weren't converted could have been converted? The fact that they have similar parameters could only mean that there are most likely other inputs you should add to improve the confidence of prediction or the precision of classification is very limited.

Another approach would be to use unsupervised learning, i.e., clustering users into groups which possibly could separate a set of customers with similar parameters among which the conversion rate is high and you can try to target the unconverted people in that group...